# How to replace content of a td having certain text in a table using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I want to replace content of a `td` having certain text in a table.

Here is the table structure I am working with.

```
<table id="quotes" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
<tbody>
<tr class="rowEven">
    <td>Store Pickup Store Pickup</td>     <!-- td content to be replaced by "hello" -->
    <td class="cartTotalDisplay">$0.00</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to replace the above mentioned content with "hello"

Comment: `$('.rowEven td:first').html('Hello');`

Comment: @Tushar i have to get td by its content not as :first

Comment: Use `td:contains('your_Text')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)** selector for that

```js
$("td:contains('Store Pickup Store Pickup')").text('hello');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="quotes" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="rowEven">
      <td>Store Pickup Store Pickup</td>
      <td class="cartTotalDisplay">$0.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#quotes tbody tr').find("td:contains('Store Pickup Store Pickup')").text('hello');
```

Use [:contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

> Description: Select all elements that contain the specified text.

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/tdvmcc1z/)

Answer (score 0):

try it :

```
  $('#quotes tbody tr td:first-child').html('Hello');
```

Comment: `i have to get td by its content not as :first` as commented by OP